# Why is the Combo Box wizard option "Find a record on my form" not always available?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Could someone please explain to me why when i use the auto builder to build a combo drop down box that for some forms the third option to link the box to a form is available, while on Others, the option to link the box to a form is not available.   It seems that this happens when trying to do so on more complex forms (which in clude sub forms) but i am not sure..
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third option (Find a record on this form ...) is available inside forms that have a recordsource property set (or *bound* forms). If the form has no recordsource set (*unbound*), it is unable to move between records, so the option is hidden.